# Paint() is called after getPreferredSize()

Tags: java, swing

I want to display a JTable with a customized header renderer (rotated 2-line text).

Pseudo code for setting the custom renderer:

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0..colCount).setHeaderRenderer(new TableCellHeaderRendererGraphics());
```

The class `TableCellHeaderRendererGraphics` extends `DefaultTableCellRenderer`.

Here the methods `paint(Graphics g)` and `getPreferredSize()` are overridden. In `paint` I do some stuff with text, font, Graphics2D and AffineTransform to rotate the text and display two lines in bold and plain.

The problem is that `getPreferredSize()` is called before `paint(Graphics g)`.
Q: How could i return the preferred size before i got a chance to calculate the dimension with the `Graphics` referenced only in `paint()`?

Comment: You can't :P, that's how the API works.  You can ask the component for the `FontMetrics` directly and see if that works

Comment: I think that I can see a design flaw in here - calculate component size while drawing it?? When you are about to paint, you should already now what are you going to paint, so you have to know all the bounds. Why won't you calculate your size in dedicated methods for such tasks, like get*size(). You could always implement own layout manager, just for this single component.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: thx, I think I will get it to work after your tip. First tests gives me hope. The JLabel FontMetrics can calculate the text length without Graphics2D, the height could be fixed value - will work for me.

Comment: @Antoniossss: I know what to draw (two lines of text). I also know the content of the text. But it seems that i need a Graphics context to calculate the size in pixels. How to calculate the height of a given text without Graphics context? Layout manager: I found "Creating a Custom Layout Manager" in "The Java Tutorials". Is this a good starting point to learn more about that?

Comment: You don't need that. Like @MadProgrammer mentioned, use FontMetrics

Comment: Just to answer my own question "How to calculate the height of a given text without Graphics context": getFontMetrics(font).getHeight(),.getAscent(),.getDescent(). Perfect!

Comment: You helped me a lot! Who wants to answer the question officially? I wanna donate all the reputations i own :)

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to answer my own question:
It's possible to calculate the size of the needed rectangles without a `Graphics` context. Use the components (`JLabel` in this case) method `getFontMetrics()`. 
On this class use `stringWidth(txt)` to get the width of the text. 
The heights of the text can be requested with `getFontMetrics().getHeight(),.getAscent(),.getDescent()`.